# Form field 'showon' parameter for unchecked checkbox

Tags: xml, forms, checkbox, joomla

I always used `showon="checkboxname"` to show an input field if a checkbox is **not checked** and `showon="checkboxname:1"` to show it if a checkbox is checked.

Simplified example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <field name="rmvOptionA" default="0" type="checkbox"/>
        <field name="OptionA" type="text" showon="rmvOptionA"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

This worked well for me until Joomla 3.6.5.

But `showon="checkboxname"` (unchecked checkbox) isn't working in Joomla 3.7. `showon="checkboxname:1"` still works fine.

I tried

- `showon="checkboxname:0"`
- `showon="checkboxname!:"` (from [here](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/21022/form-field-showonempty))
- `showon="checkboxname!:1"` (from [here](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/17681/form-field-showon-with-multiple-fields))
- and any combination of it that came to my mind.

I know that the colon is used for the value of a field and that checking a checkbox won't change its value.
But is there a workaround for Joomla 3.7?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `showon` is part of the [form field documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/Form_field#Showon) . Checkboxes are documented [here](https://docs.joomla.org/Checkbox_form_field_type)

What you're experiencing might be related to [pull request #6794](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/6794) which changed the behaviour of `default` and shipped as part of 3.7.

Please try if removing the `default` parameter of your field definition changes anything. Both `showon="checkboxname:0"` and `showon="checkboxname!:1"` should work. If they don't, it looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Removing and changing the `default` parameter does not change anything. 
Any suggestions where to go to report this (possible) bug.
Nevertheless, thank you for your effort.

Comment: I opened a new issue on jommla's github: (https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/17486)